# How to keep a symmetric-lens-shaped object upright using only wire?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Given a lens-shaped frame with a single crossbar running parallel to the floor, how could we keep that object upright and stable on one of its endpoints using only wire?

The shape I'm describing is similar to theta: θ

Except it's pointed at the top and bottom. See also [Lens (geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(geometry))

You can assume the frame is made from a flexible material, and that the entire frame is one contiguous unit. You can also assume we can freely affix any number of wires to any point on the object and any point on the ground.

As a follow-up, is there an efficient method of positioning the wires so we can keep the amount of wire needed as low as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Put a ring around the top 1/3 of the object then have 4 guy wires coming down to two bars fixed to the crossbar, one on each side.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "put a ring around the top 1/3", and exactly where the guy-wires would be affixed?

Answer (score 1):

Look at pairs of glasses as they are wire holding a lens.